# Is there special reason why online services often store images with semi random name

Tags: php, image, image-processing

In real practice we see user uploaded image with name like 84b222882da311e284b222000a1fbcf6_7.jpg

Isn't it much easier and structured to just store image as
/username/101.jpg
/username/102.jpg
(For example you can have a database table for images and you can then simply use the index as file name.)

What are the practical consideration here? I guess one would have to check every time whether a newly generated random name is not in the database? Is there concern about obfuscation?

Comment: I don't find your way easier. It's actually more complicated.

Comment: I mean isn't the second approach more intuitive and well structured? For example you can have a database table for images and you can then simply use the index as file name.

Comment: You can have random names, or names which are the hash of the file content, and put those in a database. Just as easy. "Intuitive" is not necessarily "easiest".

Comment: also, if you are using the hash as the filename, you can generally tell if the same image exact has already been uploaded. If you can find two different images with the same hash, you would probably be pretty awesome too.

Comment: One reason is that when a file is named 101.jpg, someone like me might try names like 100.jpg,102.jpg, 103.jpg to see what else the user has stored, which is not always what the user would like to happen. The other thing is that a name like 84b222882da311e284b222000a1fbcf6 could be a checksum of the file, which can ensure that file has not been replaced with a false file and the _7 ensures a unique name.

Answer (score 2):

Typically it's done for two reasons.

1. To have unique filenames.
2. Makes it difficult to guess image filenames (stops people from just entering the next image in the URL and seeing the image).

Answer (score 2):

> Isn't it much easier and structured to just store image as /username/101.jpg /username/102.jpg

Not at all. That way requires a directory listing to get the highest number used, and presents issues with deletions - do you reuse the ID? 101.jpg and 102.jpg are at *least* as arbitrary as 84b222882da311e284b222000a1fbcf6.jpg, which is likely a hash of the file content or the file's ID in the database.